# Empty csv file showing non empty in report generation in non-gui mode in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I am trying to generate an HTML report dashboard for JMeter test in NON-GUI mode with a command

```
jmeter -n -t C:\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin\DeviceManagementSystem1.jmx -l C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\Reports\Report.csv -e -o C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\Reports\Htmlreport\Report
```

it is showing error

```
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Results file:C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\Reports\Report.csv is not empty
```

But I have made an empty CSV file by saving an empty .xlxs file as CSV file

Answer (score 1):

Add [`-f` command line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) (available since [JMeter 2.13](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/4-things-you-should-know-about-jmeter-213/)) to your JMeter startup line like:

```
jmeter -n -t C:\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin\DeviceManagementSystem1.jmx -l C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\Reports\Report.csv -f -e -o C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\Reports\Htmlreport\Report
```

This parameter will "tell" JMeter to overwrite the existing results file and the HTML reporting dashboard folder with the new results.

See [Bug 58164](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58164) for more information